# Не играет видео в плеере <video>

Tags: html, видео

Загрузил видео на сервер. На странице вызываю плеер

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
<source src="/video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Но видео не воспроизводится, хотя идет его загрузка. Локально все работает.

Comment: как вы узнали что идёт загрузка ? думаю вам надо в src прописать полный путь начиная с домена, http://vahssite.ru/video/video.mp4

Comment: загрузка идет смотрел по вкладке Network отладчика. Предположение, что что-то не так с content-type. Но в htaccess тоже все прописал.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему победили, может кому будет полезно.
В процессе тестирования страницы с видеоплеером стало понятно, что маленькие по размеру файлы воспроизводились без проблем, а вот большие не показываются. При этом, файл вроде как передается и content-type отображается правильный.
Выяснилось, что проблема была в настройках сервера. А именно в HTTP range на Nginx.

Comment: Таки какая именно проблема с range-то?

Comment: Скинули HTTP range в ноль  и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Забыли `autoplay` поставить:

```
<video autoplay width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
<source src="/video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не все так просто. Файл размером меньше воспроизводится без проблем. А этот большой - никак не отображается.